# bitcoinj sendCoins method and Coin value

Tags: transactions, bitcoinj, balance

I'm trying to use bitcoinj to transfer the balance of the address derived from a random private key if that balance is non-zero.

I generate the private key and derive the address fine, then I use blockchain.info's API to check the address balance fine, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong with bitcoinj.

This line:

```
wallet.sendCoins(peerGroup, destination, wallet.getBalance());
```

I don't understand where it's getting the balance from. I haven't downloaded the blockchain and I've just created a new wallet from a random private key. Does this mean bitcoinj will always see this address as empty, even when I've confirmed that it is not empty?

I want to pass the value returned from the service into sendCoins (replacing "wallet.getBalance()" with the number of satoshis in the address), but that field requires a [Coin](https://bitcoinj.org/javadoc/0.12/org/bitcoinj/core/Coin.html) and I can't figure out how to make a Coin with a specific value that I set.

How can I get this working the way that I want to? And is there any way to test it?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private final NetworkParameters params = MainNetParams.get();

    @Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        BigInteger max = new BigInteger("FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFEBAAEDCE6AF48A03BBFD25E8CD0364141", 16);
        Random rnd = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++) {
            try {
                BigInteger privkey = new BigInteger(new BigInteger(256, rnd).toString(), 10);
                while (privkey.compareTo(max) == 1) {
                    privkey = new BigInteger(new BigInteger(256, rnd).toString(), 10);
                }
                ECKey key = ECKey.fromPrivate(privkey);

                // Calculate Addresses
                String address = LegacyAddress.fromKey(params, key).toString();
                Log.d("address",address);
                key = key.decompress();
                String address2 = LegacyAddress.fromKey(params, key).toString();
                Log.d("address2",address2);

                // Use API service to check balances of the 2 address derived from the 1 randomly-generated private key
                checkBalance(privkey, address);
                checkBalance(privkey, address2);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("Error in Main:", e.toString() + "<");
            }
        }
    }

    private void transfer(BigInteger privkey, Long sats) throws BlockStoreException, InsufficientMoneyException, InterruptedException {
        Log.d("transferring coins", "from privkey:" + privkey.toString() + "<");

        // Import the private key to a fresh wallet.
        Wallet wallet = Wallet.createDeterministic(params, Script.ScriptType.P2PKH);
        wallet.importKey(ECKey.fromPrivate(privkey));
        Address destination = LegacyAddress.fromBase58(params, "bc1quecavdwnygmfvewvavwnzv3m5gyv3svjj8dvg5");

        // send coins
        final MemoryBlockStore blockStore = new MemoryBlockStore(params);
        BlockChain chain = new BlockChain(params, wallet, blockStore);
        final PeerGroup peerGroup = new PeerGroup(params, chain);
        wallet.sendCoins(peerGroup, destination, wallet.getBalance()); // how does it get the balance???

        // Wait a few seconds to let the packets flush out to the network (ugly).
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        peerGroup.stopAsync();

    }

    private void checkBalance(BigInteger privkey, String address) {
        String url = "https://blockchain.info/balance?active=" + address;
        String balance = "";
        JsonObjectRequest request = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null,
                response -> {
                    try {
                        Long sats = response.getJSONObject(address).getLong("final_balance");
                        //Long btc = sats / 100000000;
                        if(sats > 0){
                            Log.d("Transferring", privkey + ":" + address + ":" + sats + "BTC");
                            transfer(privkey, sats);
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException | InterruptedException | BlockStoreException | InsufficientMoneyException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }, Throwable::printStackTrace);
        mQueue.add(request);
    }
}
```